# Go: get dotenv values and keep it at compilation

Tags: go

I'm developing a Go app on osx environment to use it on ubuntu linux, it's writing data to local PostgreSQL database, I'm currently storing database credentials data into an `.env` file ([golobby/dotenv](https://github.com/golobby/dotenv)) but I'd like to store it in the code instead.

Because I have to recompile the code on ubuntu linux, how to have my code integrate credentials from the `.env` file at compilation, so that the executable won't need this `.env` file ?

Or maybe there's a better approach to such problem ?

Comment: You can cross-compile Go, you can compile to linux on OS-X. Doesn't this solve your problem?

Comment: you can define a constant for the credentials and access it though.

Comment: you should not store secrets in your code.

Comment: You do not want to bundle credentials into the binary. Unless maybe they are default credentials. In that case look into using go:embed. It compiles files into variables in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to bundle credentials into the binary. Unless maybe they are default credentials. In that case look into using go:embed. It compiles files into variables in the source code.

```golang
//go:embed path/to/my_default_credentials
var defaultCredentials []byte
```

As The Fool mentioned, taking credentials at runtime, such as a through a `flag` is the preferred and secure solution.

Comment: What is the most appropriate way to deal with such credentials if not bundling it into the binary ?

Comment: @DevonDahon, the most appropriate way is providing them at runtime.

Comment: @TheFool you mean as an argument in the command line ?

Comment: @DevonDahon, you can also use os.GetEnv or LookupEnv in your code and then your set them in your environment where you run the app. See https://12factor.net/config